# Is it a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Prove or disprove: let $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a mapping with the following properties: for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $x\mapsto f\left(x,y\right)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $y\mapsto f\left(x,y\right)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

My intuition says it's not true, but I can't think of a simple counterexample.

Comment: if you add the condition that $f$ sends compact sets to compact sets then you have your conclusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true. See $\S18$ Exercise $12$ from [Munkres' book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292).

[image]

Comment: Another reference: this is  Example 9.1 in Gelbaum and Olmstead's *Counterexamples in Analysis*.

Comment: Note that $F$ is given in polar coordinates by $F(r,\theta) = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}$ which sheds some light on the geometry of the counterexample and from where it came from.